# How to have projects in a sln and not compile few of them .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I have a very big solution in visual studio and there are some 10 projects in it. For some reason I actually want to move 2 of them to the other solution. Since this is a dirty fix and just for time being I do not want to mess up with the big solution by removing them since there are dependency setting and project build orders which I am not properly aware of . i want to do some settings such that everything in the big solution remains as it is but those 2 projects should not be compiled in my TFS otherwise it throws error due to some of the my code changes. Can anyone suggest any config changes? What can I do to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the solution build configurations you can select which projects will get compiled for each build configuration. (See Screenshot) You will need to set each of the build configurations (Debug/Release/Etc) and platforms (x86/x64/AnyCPU) individually.

[image: Configuration Manager Screenshot]

Of course if any of your other projects have the non-built projects as references, you'll need to remove those direct references as well or there will be compilation errors for obvious reasons.

Comment: _Thank you so much_ @theB